# How can I use Chef Orchestration tool to output bug type labels?

Tags: chef-infra, orchestration

Hello I'm doing some research on bug classification and I've come across this article "Bug classification using machine and Deep Learning Algorithms", in which they say:

> A Bug tracking system called Atlassian JIRA was used to collect the bug list. The first level of errors were essentially the output provided by the Chef Orchestration tool. The errors, in csv format, were used as an input to the algorithms. The dataset consisted of
> 948 samples. The dataset was categorized into 5 classes

And then they name all the classes to which the bugs fell into (i.e: Missing file, Missing Declaration etc). The researchers don't give any more details as to how they use Chef to do this. I've never used Chef and it seems kinda confusing to me since I'm new to it, and I can't really understand how it would do this. Can somebody enlighten me?